# Is there any God who doesn’t regard law of karma as fundamental aspect of Universe?

Tags: karma

Law of karma is fundamental to life as is elucidated by Lord Krishna in Bhagwat Gita.
However I think there are Gods who do not regard law of karma as fundamental aspect of Universe. Mostly they are outside Hindu religion.
But is there any God in Hindu religion who does not require your karma to be pure to give you a boon ?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: Which part ? Law of Karma ? Or Is there any God who can act in your favour irrespective of your Karma demanding only devotion ?

Comment: "God' is an inexact term when you try and apply it to Hinduism. Do you mean Nirguna Brahman, Saguna Brahman, or the devis, or what??